# systemctl keeps timing out on service restart

Tags: centos, systemd, timeout, polkit

I'm running CentOS 7.2; see below:

```
# systemctl stop firewalld
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to stop firewalld.service: Connection timed out
Failed to get load state of firewalld.service: Connection timed out
```

`journalctl` just reports the following error: `[system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1': timed out`

I found this bug for [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1447654) and a possible related one for a RHEL 7 [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1013867).

Comment: for a quick-fix: You can get rid of this error by rebooting the machine. (But I am not sure whether it will come up again.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an issue with `polkit.service`; it was not starting for me.

After further investigation I found that the `polkitd` user did not exist. Then `yum reinstall polkit` and `systemctl start polkit` fixed the issue.

I debugged this by running `polkitd` directly: `/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd`

Comment: tried this solution, but when calling `systemctl start polkit` I get the same error: `Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to start polkit.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status polkit.service' for details.
`

Comment: What do you mean by manually? ( I am typing these commands manually into the shell. I am a newbie regarding linux commands.)

Comment: this is the result (but mind that I rebooted the server in the mean time, which got rid of the error in question): `Successfully changed to user polkitd ---
Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d ---
Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d ---
Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules ---
Entering main event loop ---
Connected to the system bus ---
Lost the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 - exiting ---
Shutting down ---
Exiting with code 0
`

Answer (score 0):

it could be a dbus problem. consider to reinstall one.

```
apt install dbus
```

reboot after installing as dbus configs gets upgraded only after.

Comment: Notice that the OP is using CentOS.